# How to get function code object from bytecode?

Tags: python, disassembly

I need to create a call graph of python function and then modify bytecode of some functions.

I started to play with disassembly and found that function is make by `MAKE_FUNCTION` opcode and the code object somehow passed to it

```
 32          96 LOAD_CONST              25 ((None, None, True, 'off', None, False))
             98 LOAD_CONST              15 (<code object foobar at 0x7fc46bff6d20, file "foo.py", line 25>)
            100 LOAD_CONST              16 ('foo')
            102 MAKE_FUNCTION            1
            104 STORE_NAME              15 ('fun')
```

Okay, I found roots of the callgraph in this file, but what to do next? How do I actually get this code object?

Answer (score 1):

The function type is what you want. You can get it from the `types` module (where it is `types.FunctionType`) or just `type(lambda:0)`. Do a `help()` on the type to see the arguments required to create a function object.

The primary thing you need to construct the function is the code object. You can get that from an existing function `f` using `f.func_code`. If you are modifying the bytecode you will need to create a new code object to contain it. Its type can be obtained using `type()` as with the function and doing a `help()` on the type will tell you what you need to pass in.

If you are basing the new function on an existing one, then you can dig most of what you need out of the existing function. See [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) in the `inspect` module documentation to see what attributes of functions and code objects contain things of interest to you.

Comment: Um... I don't see how this answers my question. I have a pyc file, I've disassembled it with `dis.dis`. Then what?

Comment: So you have the function, or you couldn't have disassembled it with `dis`. So the code object of function `f` is `f.func_code` and the bytecode string is `f.func_code.co_code`. You say you want to modify the bytecode, and once you do that you will need to build a new function from it, which you can do using the code and function types.

Comment: What if I don't have source files and have only compiled files?

Comment: Okay, it's in `co_consts`